# I got a green overlay in my video when using multiply blend mode in ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, overlay, blend

I´m trying to blend two videos with the multiply blend mode. But I got a green overlay in the resulting video.

This is a image where are one frame of each input video and one frame of the resulting video
[Composition](https://www.flickr.com/photos/95739404@N06/14087765973/)

I execute this command line:

```
sudo ffmpeg -y -i video_top.avi -i video_background.mp4 -filter_complex "blend=all_mode=multiply" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

This is the ffmpeg output:

```
built on Mar 20 2014 14:51:45 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
libavutil      52. 67.100 / 52. 67.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'video_top.avi':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf54.29.104
Duration: 00:00:10.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 688 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 682 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video_background.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: mp42mp41
creation_time   : 2014-04-29 12:51:17
Duration: 00:00:08.90, start: 0.033333, bitrate: 3417 kb/s
Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], 3408 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2014-04-29 12:51:17
  handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] 264 - core 142 r2 d6b4e63 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.34.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 704x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 11:9], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> blend:top
Stream #1:0 (h264) -> blend:bottom
blend -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  268 fps=121 q=-1.0 Lsize=     732kB time=00:00:10.64 bitrate= 563.2kbits/s
video:728kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.539149%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.96  size: 35789
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] frame P:77    Avg QP:21.68  size:  5552
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] frame B:189   Avg QP:24.79  size:  1298
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] consecutive B-frames:  1.1% 11.2% 10.1% 77.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] mb I  I16..4: 30.7% 36.5% 32.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] mb P  I16..4:  3.0%  2.6%  0.4%  P16..4: 41.3% 14.4%  6.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:31.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 43.8%  2.8%  0.3%  direct: 0.2%  skip:52.5%  L0:42.2% L1:56.1% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] 8x8 transform intra:40.7% inter:79.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.9% 29.0% 8.3% inter: 7.1% 4.5% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] i16 v,h,dc,p: 23% 19% 33% 26%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 15% 45%  3%  3%  3%  5%  3%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32% 23% 19%  4%  3%  3%  7%  2%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] i8c dc,h,v,p: 67% 15% 16%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] ref P L0: 67.4% 10.1% 17.0%  5.6%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] ref B L0: 91.6%  7.3%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x2e42660] kb/s:555.48
```

I don't know what is wrong, and using others blend modes got others ridiculous results, like having a pink overlay in the video.

Suggestions will be well appreciated, thanks very much.